# C# How to automatically focus on updated row after updating row in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My question is asked a lot but, I don't quite get the right output that I want to happen. As you can see on my question, that's the output what I want to get help with. I tried several codes to do it but it doesn't meet my required ouput. Here's the thing that I tried when I select a row (Fullrowselect), and update this row it returns to the first row of my datagridview and if I delete this code, it returns all row not the updated row only. I hope someone would be able to help me.

Here's what I've tried.

```
private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
    {
        Product._UPDATEProduct(Picture, photobyte, Category.Text, Type.Text, Supplier.Text, Code.Text, Model.Text, Description.Text, Quantity.Text, Price.Text, ID);
        DisplayProductItems._DisplayProductItems(_view.dbdataset, _view.ProductList);
        _view.btn_update.Hide();
        this.Close();

        Product._UPDATEProductLog(_view.UserID, _view.UserType, _view.Names, Activity, date, Time, ID);
    }
        _view.ProductList.Focus();
        _view.ProductList.CurrentCell = _view.ProductList.Rows[0].Cells[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move these line to the end of the function:

```
_view.ProductList.CurrentRow.Selected = false;
_view.ProductList.Focus();
_view.ProductList.CurrentCell = _view.ProductList.Rows[0].Cells[2];
```

Hope it helpful for you

Comment: I tried yours, but its still returning on the first row

Comment: Actually, the code run OK, but the focus is overlap by selected row. The solution is set selected row to false. I updated my answer. Regard!

Comment: Still same thing happen it returns to the first row but one thing is change the selected row is off

Comment: is not it set focus to Cell 2 of first row ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question

Comment: _view.ProductList.CurrentCell = _view.ProductList.Rows[0].Cells[2]; You are setting the focus to a cell of first row. Then it is in your first row.